Can't get data with URL in Postman, but can with passing by key-value
I'm not very familiar with Postman but why GET request returns data when checkbox is marked and without url parameter, like this:

and when I try to put url parameter and unmark checkbox, then doesn't work, like this:

As I understand ? symbol means query in database for value that follows that sign. Does it have anything to do with `x-www-form-urlencoded ?
I also tried with code in React:
useEffect(() => {
fetch(
      `http://IP:PORT/api/dohvati_nekretninu/{idnekretnina}`
    )
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error("PROBLEM SE DOGODIO u GET-u");
        }
        console.log("res", res);
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((jsonData) => {
        console.log("CCC", jsonData);
        setData(jsonData);
})
      .catch((err) => console.error("Error fetching data:", err));
  }, []);

and I got this (with nothing inside body):




Postman send both, you can see the raw query when clicking in the right icon (code icon), the problem is probably the code you made is only getting the "form parameter" request value, acctually if you defined the page to receive form parameter, doesn't make sense to also have search values, except if it is a legate code.
Also...
if this is the react code you made:       http://IP:PORT/api/dohvati_nekretninu/{idnekretnina}
It is sending noting but only a strange URL paramter with brackets, you shoould do this instead:       http://IP:PORT/api/dohvati_nekretninu?idnekretnina=${idnekretnina}
And maybe it will work, if you are getting the search parameters in the backend

I tried with this also http://IP:PORT/api/dohvati_nekretninu?idnekretnina=${idnekretnina} and then on backend is received /api/get_nekretninu and empty object {}, it should receive {idnekretnina: 33"}
But why in postman I got empty array in data when I put this in GET request http://IP:PORT/api/dohvati_nekretninu?idnekretnina=${idnekretnina} ?

Can you share how you are getting those parameters in backend? And how you are returning, if you share that, I may help a little more
